# Get function to go through each individual group in data set instead of the whole dataset,

Tags: r, statistics

My function goes through a list of datasets and returns the p value, statistic and ci. How can I make it run through all the individual datasets in a list instead of calculating the statistics for all of the list.

[image: my dataset]

[image: function]

I have FindOST(listofdatas[1:5000],2,alt = "two-sided",.95) but it does not help

it gives a an average of all the listofdats

Comment: While someone will help on this.  I cannot access PC to test my ideas. But picture posting is not going to help. Please provide reproducible data. Check / google how to share reproducible data on SO. Will help you in long run to get great support here. Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.